# Java generics. Getting .class attribute

Tags: java, generics, swagger

I know that for get a class name from a java Class I can do `MyClass.class`, but I cannot do this on parametrized class. For example I want to do `ParametrizedClass<MyClass>.class`.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

I want to get class from parametrized class for generating Swagger documentation.

Comment: No, it is not, and is not necessary. The generic parameter does not influence the `.class` object. Generics in Java are different from, e.g., template parameters in C++ where each parameterized instance generates a separate "class".

Comment: [`ideone.com` demo](https://ideone.com/aQ0jbM) for my claim.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)

Comment: You need something like [`TypeToken`](https://guava.dev/typetoken) to do anything like this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, `ParameterizedClass<MyClass>.class` does not compile …

But let's assume it would …

Then you would encounter the surprising fact that

`ParameterizedClass<MyClass>.class.equals( ParameterizedClass<String>.class )`

is always true. In fact, even

`ParameterizedClass<MyClass>.class == ParameterizedClass<String>.class`

would be always true.

This means that you can just use `ParameterizedClass.class` to get the `Class`object for your class – and that compiles …

The reason for that the TypeParameter will be 'erased' during/after compilation. It is not part of the code in the '.class' file.